# String delimiter is affecting some instances of its individual characters

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

So basically, I'm trying to print out a human readable list of file and directory sizes (without the current directory listed) with the following code

```
du -arh | sort -nr | tail -n +2 | awk -F"./" '{print $1 $2 $3}' | head -n $NUM
```

The NUM variable is just an argument given for the amount of items listed.

The output of the above without the awk delimiter command is

> 4.0K  ./url-list
>   4.0K  ./testurl.sh
>   4.0K  ./diskhogger.sh
>   4.0K  ./backup/url-list
>   4.0K  ./backup.sh

However, adding the awk command outputs

> 4.0K  url-list
>   4.0K    testurl.sh
>   4.0K    diskhogger.sh
>   4.0K    backuurl-list
>   4.0K    backup.sh

A similar output occurs whenever there is a notable subdirectory.

> ./Library/Cache - LibrarCache, etc.

To be clear, I am attempting to cut out the "./" at the beginning of the file name without affecting the other forward slashes. My preferred output would be:

> 4.0K  url-list
>   4.0K    testurl.sh
>   4.0K    diskhogger.sh
>   4.0K    backup/url-list
>   4.0K    backup.sh

where the "backup/url-list" isn't affected.

Is the '.' in my delimiter a special character I don't know about? If not, what exactly is going on here?

I'm new to shell so any info on this would be great.

Thanks!

Edited for clarity.

Comment: `.` means any char, what you want is just `sed 's_./__'`

Comment: Need to escape that `.`, too:  `sed '_\./__'`

Comment: Awesome that's exactly the answer I was looking for. Can you post it as an actual answer so I can award it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-F"./"` - is treated as *"any character followed by forward slash"*.
It's taken as regex pattern where `.` means "any character" in terms of regex expressions. 
To use *"dot followed by slash"* `./` as a delimiter use one of the following approaches:

- `.` within character class

  ```
  awk -F"[.]/" '{print $1,$2,$3}'
  ```

---

- `.` escaped

  ```
  awk -F'\\./' '{print $1,$2,$3}'
  ```

Answer (score 2):

you can get rid of some other commands if you're using `awk`

```
du -arh | sort -nr | awk -v len="$NUM" 'NR>1{gsub("\\.\\/",""); print} NR==len{exit}'
```

or simply use

```
... | sed 's_\./__' | head ...
```

Comment: sed is what you need here. awk is really neat and nice, but here sed is the most appropriate

Answer (score 1):

Yes. awk treats the delimiter as a regular expression. A "." in a regular expression matches any character. Hence awk will split your lines up everywhere there is a character preceding a "/".
If you wish to match a literal ".", the easiest way of doing it is to put it in square brackets, to make it a character class, matching only the character "."

You end up with

```
du -arh | sort -nr | tail -n +2 | awk -F"[.]/" '{print $1 $2}' | head -n $NUM
```

However, note that this is not your only problem. If you have a directory whose name ends with a "." and that directory contains files, you will have more than one entry of "./" on some lines in the results from "du". (e.g. a file named "bar" in a directory named "foo." gives you "foo./bar".) A better solution is therefore to use the sub() function in awk to replace the first instance of "./" with "".

```
du -arh | sort -nr | tail -n +2 | awk '{sub("./",""); print}' | head -n $NUM
```

Comment: This complements and explains some of the changes @karakfa made to my script as well. Thanks!